# Program alters variable value during execution

Tags: c, runtime-error

I'm writing the following C program.  At this stage, the program should take input from the user and store it into the variable `days`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10

int main(){
    int days = 0;
    int high_temp[SIZE] = {0};
    int low_temp[SIZE] = {0};

    printf("---=== IPC Temperature Calculator V2.0 ===---\n");

    if ((days < 3) || (days > 10)) {

        printf("Please enter the number of days, between 3 and 10, inclusive: %d");
        scanf("%d", &days);

        while ((days < 3) || (days > 10)) {
            printf("\nInvalid entry, please enter a number between 3 and 10, inclusive: ");
            scanf("%d", &days);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < days; i++){
        printf("\nDay %d - High: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &high_temp);

        printf("\nDay %d - High: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &low_temp);
    }

}
```

However, during execution, the problem assigns an absurd value to `days`:

```
---=== IPC Temperature Calculator V2.0 ===---
Please enter the number of days, between 3 and 10, inclusive: 87585440
```

Mind you that `days` is initialized as 0 and the value is suppose to change within the if statement.

Comment: The problem with this `printf("Please enter the number of days, between 3 and 10, inclusive: %d");`, you did not give a parameter for the `%d`. It will print values from the stack.

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but `scanf("%d", &high_temp);` is also wrong.  `scanf` is expecting a pointer to an integer, but you are passing a pointer to an array.  It is the wrong type, and moreover each number read is going to overwrite the previous. In context it looks like maybe you want `scanf("%d", &high_temp[i]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement

```
printf("Please enter the number of days, between 3 and 10, inclusive: %d");
```

has undefined behavior. Remove `%d` from the outputted string.

Just write

```
printf("Please enter the number of days, between 3 and 10, inclusive: ");
```

If you want to use the specifier as a prompt then write

```
printf("Please enter the number of days, between 3 and 10, inclusive: %%d");
```

that is used `%%d`.

Comment: The `printf` command does not send a newline, nor is the stream flushed. On many systems, doing this to the console would not display the prompt until some later point.

Answer (score 2):

Your `printf()` call contains a format specifier of `%d` but you aren't passing an integer after the format. That's undefined behavior and it's pulling some unknown value from memory.

If you want to print the value of `days` you need to pass it in the function call. If not then remove the `%d` specifier.

```
printf("Please enter the number of days, between 3 and 10, inclusive: %d", days);
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go, hope that helps

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10
int main(){
int days = 0;
int high_temp[SIZE] = {0};
int low_temp[SIZE] = {0};

printf("---=== IPC Temperature Calculator V2.0 ===---\n");

if ((days < 3) || (days > 10)) {

    printf("Please enter the number of days, between 3 and 10, inclusive: ");
    scanf("%d", &days);

    while ((days < 3) || (days > 10)) {
        printf("\nInvalid entry, please enter a number between 3 and 10, inclusive: ");
        scanf("%d", &days);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < days; i++){
    printf("\nDay %d - High: ", (i+1));
    scanf("%d", &high_temp[i]);

    printf("\nDay %d - Low: ", (i+1));
    scanf("%d", &low_temp[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < days; i++){

   printf("\n Day # %d", (i + 1));
   printf("\n\t High: %d", high_temp[i]);
   printf("\n\t Low: %d", low_temp[i]); 
}
```

}

Comment: What's with the 2 for loops?

Comment: the first one is to read the low, high tempreture, the second one just to print them out